# Spring MVC 4 with MyBatis error.

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mybatis, ibatis

I have created Spring MVC 4 with MyBatis. I am very sure I am all set up correctly. For Some reason I am getting this error. Any help is appreciated

```
Apr 30, 2015 7:22:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [myBatisServlet] in context with path [/APMS] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'one' not found. Available parameters are [0, 1, 2, param5, 3, 4, param3, param4, param1, param2]] with root cause
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'one' not found. Available parameters are [0, 1, 2, param5, 3, 4, param3, param4, param1, param2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$ParamMap.get(MapperMethod.java:165)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.MapWrapper.get(MapWrapper.java:44)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject.getValue(MetaObject.java:116)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.createCacheKey(BaseExecutor.java:186)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.createCacheKey(CachingExecutor.java:129)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:108)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:358)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:198)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:119)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.gm.app.apms.service.WbbCodeService.getTableResult(WbbCodeService.java:24)
    at com.gm.app.apms.controller.WbbOrderStatusController.getAllOrdersResults(WbbOrderStatusController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Controller class**

```
package com.gm.app.apms.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.gm.app.apms.model.WbbOrderStatusForm;
import com.gm.app.apms.model.WbbOrderStatusResult;
import com.gm.app.apms.service.IWbbCodeService;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("wbborderstatusform")
public class WbbOrderStatusController {

    @Autowired
    private IWbbCodeService iWbbCodeService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/viewallorders", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView getAllOrdersResults  (@ModelAttribute("wbbOrderStatusForm") WbbOrderStatusForm wbbOrderStatusForm) throws Exception
        {
            System.out.println(" I AM HERE");
            String DateFrom = wbbOrderStatusForm.getDateFrom();
            String DateTo = wbbOrderStatusForm.getDateTo();
            String orderType = wbbOrderStatusForm.getOrderType();
            String distCode = wbbOrderStatusForm.getDistCode();
            String packingCode = wbbOrderStatusForm.getPackingCode();

            System.out.println("DateFrom "+DateFrom);
            System.out.println("DateTo "+DateTo);
            System.out.println("orderType "+orderType);
            System.out.println("distCode "+distCode);
            System.out.println("packingCode "+packingCode);

            ModelAndView showresult = new ModelAndView("showresults");
            List <WbbOrderStatusResult> tablelist = new ArrayList<WbbOrderStatusResult>();

            if (!DateFrom.isEmpty() && !DateTo.isEmpty() && !orderType.isEmpty() && !distCode.isEmpty() && !packingCode.isEmpty()){
                tablelist = iWbbCodeService.getTableResult(DateFrom, DateTo, orderType, distCode, packingCode);

                showresult.addObject("tablelist", tablelist);
            }
            return showresult;
        }



      @RequestMapping(value="/viewallorders", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String signup(Model model) {
            System.out.println("FIRST PART");
            WbbOrderStatusForm wbbOrderStatusForm = new WbbOrderStatusForm();
            model.addAttribute("wbbOrderStatusForm", wbbOrderStatusForm);
            return "viewallorders";
        }
}
```

**Mapper class**

```
package com.gm.app.apms.mappers;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;

import com.gm.app.apms.model.WbbOrderStatusResult;

public interface WbbCodeMapper
{
    @Select("SELECT p1.P3ORDRM0.BUYER_ORDR_NO as distOrderNo, p1.P3ORDRM0.ORDR_YEAR||p1.P3ORDRM0.ORDR_CUST_CD||p1.P3ORDRM0.ORDR_TYPE||p1.P3ORDRM0.ORDR_SEQ as gmdatOrderNo, "
            + "p1.P3ORDRM0.CNFM_DT as cnfmDt, p1.P3ORDRM0.PORT_DEST_CD as packingCode, p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_ITEM as orderedItem, "
            + "p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY as orderedPcs, Round(p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_AMT*decode(p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE,1000,1,p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE),2) as orderedAmt, "
            + "p1.P9ORDRV1.DSTR_ITEM as allocationItem, p1.P9ORDRV1.DSTR_QTY as allocationPcs, Round(p1.P9ORDRV1.DSTR_AMT*decode(p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE,1000,1,p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE),2) as allocationAmt, "
            + "DECODE(p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY,0,0,Round((p1.P9ORDRV1.DSTR_QTY / p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY )*100,2)) as allocationRate, p1.P9ORDRV1.PICK_ITEM as pickItem, "
            + "p1.P9ORDRV1.PICK_QTY as pickPcs, Round(p1.P9ORDRV1.PICK_AMT*decode(p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE,1000,1,p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE),2) as pickAmt, "
            + "DECODE(p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY,0,0,Round((p1.P9ORDRV1.PICK_QTY / p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY )*100,2)) as pickRate, p1.P9ORDRV1.PACK_ITEM as packItem, "
            + "p1.P9ORDRV1.PACK_QTY as packPcs, Round(p1.P9ORDRV1.PACK_AMT*decode(p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE,1000,1,p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE),2) as packAmt, "
            + "DECODE(p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY,0,0,Round((p1.P9ORDRV1.PICK_QTY / p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY )*100,2)) as packRate, p1.P9ORDRV1.CASE_OUT_ITEM as cargoReadyItem, "
            + "p1.P9ORDRV1.CASE_OUT_QTY as cargoReadyPcs, Round(p1.P9ORDRV1.CASE_OUT_AMT*decode(p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE,1000,1,p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE),2) as cargoReadyAmt, "
            + "DECODE(p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY,0,0,Round((p1.P9ORDRV1.CASE_OUT_QTY / p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY )*100,2)) as cargoReadyRate, p1.P9ORDRV1.SHIP_PEND_ITEM as vanningItem, "
            + "p1.P9ORDRV1.SHIP_PEND_QTY as vanningPcs, Round(p1.P9ORDRV1.SHIP_PEND_AMT*decode(p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE,1000,1,p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE),2) as vanningAmt, "
            + "DECODE(p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY,0,0,Round((p1.P9ORDRV1.SHIP_PEND_QTY / p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY )*100,2)) as vanningRate, p1.P9ORDRV1.SHIP_ITEM as shippedItem, "
            + "p1.P9ORDRV1.SHIP_QTY as shippedPcs, Round(p1.P9ORDRV1.SHIP_AMT*decode(p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE,1000,1,p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE),2) as shippedAmt, "
            + "DECODE(p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY,0,0,Round((p1.P9ORDRV1.SHIP_QTY / p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY )*100,2)) as shippedRate, p1.P9ORDRV1.BACK_ORDR_ITEM as balanceItem, "
            + "p1.P9ORDRV1.BACK_ORDR_QTY as balancePcs, Round(p1.P9ORDRV1.BACK_ORDR_AMT*decode(p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE,1000,1,p1.P3ORDRM0.MULTI_EXCH_RATE),2) as balanceAmt, "
            + "DECODE(p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY,0,0,Round((p1.P9ORDRV1.BACK_ORDR_QTY / p1.P9ORDRV1.ORDR_QTY )*100,2)) as balanceRate, decode(p1.P3ORDRM0.CURR,'KRW','USD',p1.P3ORDRM0.CURR) as cur FROM p1.P3ORDRM0, "
            + "p1.P9ORDRV1 WHERE p1.p3ordrm0.ordr_year = p1.P9ORDRV1.ordr_year(+) AND p1.p3ordrm0.ordr_cust_cd = p1.P9ORDRV1.ordr_cust_cd(+) AND p1.p3ordrm0.ordr_type = p1.P9ORDRV1.ordr_type(+) "
            + "AND p1.p3ordrm0.ordr_seq = p1.P9ORDRV1.ordr_seq (+) "
            + "AND p1.P3ORDRM0.CNFM_DT >= #{one} "
            + "AND p1.P3ORDRM0.CNFM_DT <= #{two} "
            + "AND p1.P3ORDRM0.ORDR_TYPE like '%#{three}%' "
            + "AND p1.P3ORDRM0.ORDR_CUST_CD = '#{four}' "
            + "AND p1.P3ORDRM0.ORDRM0_STAT in ('400','500','700') "
            + "AND p1.P3ORDRM0.PORT_DEST_CD LIKE '%#{five}%';")
    public List <WbbOrderStatusResult> getResult(String one, String two, String three, String four, String five);
}
```

**Model of form**

```
package com.gm.app.apms.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class WbbOrderStatusForm
{

    private String dateFrom;
    private String dateTo;
    private String orderType;
    private String packingCode;
    private String distCode;
    private String partNo;
    private String radioCond;
    private String distOrderNo;
    private String suppPartNo;
    private String suppSrc;
    private String caseStatus;
    private String caseYear;
    private String caseCustCd;
    private String caseSm;
    private String caseSeq;
    private String chk;
    private String mod;
    private String gmPartNo;
    private String suzukiPartNo;

    private Collection orderTypeCollection;
    private Collection packingCodeCollection;

    public WbbOrderStatusForm() {}

    public Collection getOrderTypeCollection()
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        //list.add(new LabelValueBean("ALL", ""));

        HashMap searchMap = new HashMap();
        searchMap.put("cdNo", "E0001");
        List result = null;
        //List result = (List) WbbCodeService.getInstance().getCodeList(searchMap);

        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        {
            HashMap resultMap = (HashMap) result.get(i);
            str = (String) resultMap.get("cdItem");
            //list.add(new LabelValueBean(str, (String) resultMap.get("cdValue")));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public void setOrderTypeCollection(Collection collection)
    {
        orderTypeCollection = collection;
    }

    public Collection getPackingCodeCollection()
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        //list.add(new LabelValueBean("ALL", ""));

        HashMap searchMap = new HashMap();
        searchMap.put("distCode", distCode);
        List result = null;
        //List result = (List) WbbCodeService.getInstance().getPackingCodeList(searchMap);

        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        {
            HashMap resultMap = (HashMap) result.get(i);
            str = (String) resultMap.get("cdValue");
            //list.add(new LabelValueBean(str, (String) resultMap.get("cdValue")));
        }
        // ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ 1ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
        if (list.size() == 1)
        {
            //list.add(new LabelValueBean("1", "1"));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public void setPackingCodeCollection(Collection collection)
    {
        packingCodeCollection = collection;
    }

    public String getDateFrom()
    {
        return dateFrom;
    }

    public void setDateFrom(String dateFrom)
    {
        this.dateFrom = dateFrom;
    }

    public String getDateTo()
    {
        return dateTo;
    }

    public void setDateTo(String dateTo)
    {
        this.dateTo = dateTo;
    }

    public String getOrderType()
    {
        return orderType;
    }

    public void setOrderType(String orderType)
    {
        this.orderType = orderType;
    }

    public String getPackingCode()
    {
        return packingCode;
    }

    public void setPackingCode(String packingCode)
    {
        this.packingCode = packingCode;
    }

    public String getDistCode()
    {
        return distCode;
    }

    public void setDistCode(String distCode)
    {
        this.distCode = distCode;
    }

    public String getPartNo()
    {
        return partNo;
    }

    public void setPartNo(String partNo)
    {
        this.partNo = partNo;
    }

    public String getRadioCond()
    {
        return radioCond;
    }

    public void setRadioCond(String radioCond)
    {
        this.radioCond = radioCond;
    }

    public String getDistOrderNo()
    {
        return distOrderNo;
    }

    public void setDistOrderNo(String distOrderNo)
    {
        this.distOrderNo = distOrderNo;
    }

    public String getSuppPartNo()
    {
        return suppPartNo;
    }

    public void setSuppPartNo(String suppPartNo)
    {
        this.suppPartNo = suppPartNo;
    }

    public String getSuppSrc()
    {
        return suppSrc;
    }

    public void setSuppSrc(String suppSrc)
    {
        this.suppSrc = suppSrc;
    }

    public String getCaseStatus()
    {
        return caseStatus;
    }

    public void setCaseStatus(String caseStatus)
    {
        this.caseStatus = caseStatus;
    }

    public String getCaseYear()
    {
        return caseYear;
    }

    public void setCaseYear(String caseYear)
    {
        this.caseYear = caseYear;
    }

    public String getCaseCustCd()
    {
        return caseCustCd;
    }

    public void setCaseCustCd(String caseCustCd)
    {
        this.caseCustCd = caseCustCd;
    }

    public String getCaseSm()
    {
        return caseSm;
    }

    public void setCaseSm(String caseSm)
    {
        this.caseSm = caseSm;
    }

    public String getCaseSeq()
    {
        return caseSeq;
    }

    public void setCaseSeq(String caseSeq)
    {
        this.caseSeq = caseSeq;
    }

    public String getChk()
    {
        return chk;
    }

    public void setChk(String chk)
    {
        this.chk = chk;
    }

    public String getMod()
    {
        return mod;
    }

    public void setMod(String mod)
    {
        this.mod = mod;
    }

    public String getGmPartNo()
    {
        return gmPartNo;
    }

    public void setGmPartNo(String gmPartNo)
    {
        this.gmPartNo = gmPartNo;
    }

    public String getSuzukiPartNo()
    {
        return suzukiPartNo;
    }

    public void setSuzukiPartNo(String suzukiPartNo)
    {
        this.suzukiPartNo = suzukiPartNo;
    }
}
```

**Model of Result**

```
package com.gm.app.apms.model;

public class WbbOrderStatusResult {

    private String distOrderNo;
    private String gmdatOrderNo;
    private String cnfmDt;
    private String packingCode;
    private String orderedItem;
    private String orderedPcs;
    private String orderedAmt;
    private String allocationItem;
    private String allocationPcs;
    private String allocationAmt;
    private String allocationRate;
    private String pickItem;
    private String pickPcs;
    private String pickAmt;
    private String pickRate;
    private String packItem;
    private String packPcs;
    private String packAmt;
    private String packRate;
    private String cargoReadyItem;
    private String cargoReadyPcs;
    private String cargoReadyAmt;
    private String cargoReadyRate;
    private String vanningItem;
    private String vanningPcs;
    private String vanningAmt;
    private String vanningRate;
    private String shippedItem;
    private String shippedPcs;
    private String shippedAmt;
    private String shippedRate;
    private String balanceItem;
    private String balancePcs;
    private String balanceAmt;
    private String balanceRate;
    private String cur;

    public String getDistOrderNo() {
        return distOrderNo;
    }
    public void setDistOrderNo(String distOrderNo) {
        this.distOrderNo = distOrderNo;
    }
    public String getGmdatOrderNo() {
        return gmdatOrderNo;
    }
    public void setGmdatOrderNo(String gmdatOrderNo) {
        this.gmdatOrderNo = gmdatOrderNo;
    }
    public String getCnfmDt() {
        return cnfmDt;
    }
    public void setCnfmDt(String cnfmDt) {
        this.cnfmDt = cnfmDt;
    }
    public String getPackingCode() {
        return packingCode;
    }
    public void setPackingCode(String packingCode) {
        this.packingCode = packingCode;
    }
    public String getOrderedItem() {
        return orderedItem;
    }
    public void setOrderedItem(String orderedItem) {
        this.orderedItem = orderedItem;
    }
    public String getOrderedPcs() {
        return orderedPcs;
    }
    public void setOrderedPcs(String orderedPcs) {
        this.orderedPcs = orderedPcs;
    }
    public String getOrderedAmt() {
        return orderedAmt;
    }
    public void setOrderedAmt(String orderedAmt) {
        this.orderedAmt = orderedAmt;
    }
    public String getAllocationItem() {
        return allocationItem;
    }
    public void setAllocationItem(String allocationItem) {
        this.allocationItem = allocationItem;
    }
    public String getAllocationPcs() {
        return allocationPcs;
    }
    public void setAllocationPcs(String allocationPcs) {
        this.allocationPcs = allocationPcs;
    }
    public String getAllocationAmt() {
        return allocationAmt;
    }
    public void setAllocationAmt(String allocationAmt) {
        this.allocationAmt = allocationAmt;
    }
    public String getAllocationRate() {
        return allocationRate;
    }
    public void setAllocationRate(String allocationRate) {
        this.allocationRate = allocationRate;
    }
    public String getPickItem() {
        return pickItem;
    }
    public void setPickItem(String pickItem) {
        this.pickItem = pickItem;
    }
    public String getPickPcs() {
        return pickPcs;
    }
    public void setPickPcs(String pickPcs) {
        this.pickPcs = pickPcs;
    }
    public String getPickAmt() {
        return pickAmt;
    }
    public void setPickAmt(String pickAmt) {
        this.pickAmt = pickAmt;
    }
    public String getPickRate() {
        return pickRate;
    }
    public void setPickRate(String pickRate) {
        this.pickRate = pickRate;
    }
    public String getPackItem() {
        return packItem;
    }
    public void setPackItem(String packItem) {
        this.packItem = packItem;
    }
    public String getPackPcs() {
        return packPcs;
    }
    public void setPackPcs(String packPcs) {
        this.packPcs = packPcs;
    }
    public String getPackAmt() {
        return packAmt;
    }
    public void setPackAmt(String packAmt) {
        this.packAmt = packAmt;
    }
    public String getPackRate() {
        return packRate;
    }
    public void setPackRate(String packRate) {
        this.packRate = packRate;
    }
    public String getCargoReadyItem() {
        return cargoReadyItem;
    }
    public void setCargoReadyItem(String cargoReadyItem) {
        this.cargoReadyItem = cargoReadyItem;
    }
    public String getCargoReadyPcs() {
        return cargoReadyPcs;
    }
    public void setCargoReadyPcs(String cargoReadyPcs) {
        this.cargoReadyPcs = cargoReadyPcs;
    }
    public String getCargoReadyAmt() {
        return cargoReadyAmt;
    }
    public void setCargoReadyAmt(String cargoReadyAmt) {
        this.cargoReadyAmt = cargoReadyAmt;
    }
    public String getCargoReadyRate() {
        return cargoReadyRate;
    }
    public void setCargoReadyRate(String cargoReadyRate) {
        this.cargoReadyRate = cargoReadyRate;
    }
    public String getVanningItem() {
        return vanningItem;
    }
    public void setVanningItem(String vanningItem) {
        this.vanningItem = vanningItem;
    }
    public String getVanningPcs() {
        return vanningPcs;
    }
    public void setVanningPcs(String vanningPcs) {
        this.vanningPcs = vanningPcs;
    }
    public String getVanningAmt() {
        return vanningAmt;
    }
    public void setVanningAmt(String vanningAmt) {
        this.vanningAmt = vanningAmt;
    }
    public String getVanningRate() {
        return vanningRate;
    }
    public void setVanningRate(String vanningRate) {
        this.vanningRate = vanningRate;
    }
    public String getShippedItem() {
        return shippedItem;
    }
    public void setShippedItem(String shippedItem) {
        this.shippedItem = shippedItem;
    }
    public String getShippedPcs() {
        return shippedPcs;
    }
    public void setShippedPcs(String shippedPcs) {
        this.shippedPcs = shippedPcs;
    }
    public String getShippedAmt() {
        return shippedAmt;
    }
    public void setShippedAmt(String shippedAmt) {
        this.shippedAmt = shippedAmt;
    }
    public String getShippedRate() {
        return shippedRate;
    }
    public void setShippedRate(String shippedRate) {
        this.shippedRate = shippedRate;
    }
    public String getBalanceItem() {
        return balanceItem;
    }
    public void setBalanceItem(String balanceItem) {
        this.balanceItem = balanceItem;
    }
    public String getBalancePcs() {
        return balancePcs;
    }
    public void setBalancePcs(String balancePcs) {
        this.balancePcs = balancePcs;
    }
    public String getBalanceAmt() {
        return balanceAmt;
    }
    public void setBalanceAmt(String balanceAmt) {
        this.balanceAmt = balanceAmt;
    }
    public String getBalanceRate() {
        return balanceRate;
    }
    public void setBalanceRate(String balanceRate) {
        this.balanceRate = balanceRate;
    }
    public String getCur() {
        return cur;
    }
    public void setCur(String cur) {
        this.cur = cur;
    }
}
```

**Service Interface**

```
package com.gm.app.apms.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.gm.app.apms.model.WbbOrderStatusResult;

public interface IWbbCodeService
{

    public List<WbbOrderStatusResult> getTableResult(String one, String two, String three, String four, String five);
}
```

**Service Implementation**

```
package com.gm.app.apms.service;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.gm.app.apms.mappers.StudentMapper;
import com.gm.app.apms.mappers.WbbCodeMapper;
import com.gm.app.apms.model.WbbOrderStatusResult;


@Service("IWbbCodeService")
public class WbbCodeService implements IWbbCodeService
{
    @Autowired
    private WbbCodeMapper wbbCodeMapper;

    @Override
    public List<WbbOrderStatusResult> getTableResult(String one, String two,
            String three, String four, String five) {

        return wbbCodeMapper.getResult(one, two, three, four, five);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solutions was to use @Param annotation

```
public List <WbbOrderStatusResult> getResult(@Param("one")String one, @Param("two")String two, @Param("three")String three, @Param("four")String four, @Param("five")String five);
```

Answer (score 1):

Kothari's own answer would work, but in your xml mapping you could just do

## {param1,jdbcType=xxx} #{param2,jdbcType=xxx} etc.....